# Attempted to call an undefined method named "getDefaultName"

Tags: symfony

I want to upgrade symfony from 3.3 to 3.4 but when I do a `composer update`, I've got this error :

```
[RuntimeException]
An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedMethodException: Attempted to call an undefined method named "getDefaultName" of class "Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineCacheBundle\Command\ContainsCommand". in /srv/http/ocim.formations/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/DependencyInjectionAddConsoleCommandPass.php:61
Stack trace:
#0 /srv/http/ocim.formations/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/Compiler.php(141): Symfony\Component\Console\DependencyInjection\AddConsoleCommandPass->process(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder))
#1 /srv/http/ocim.formations/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php(759): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder))
#2 /srv/http/ocim.formations/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(643): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile in /srv/http/ocim.formations/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/DependencyInjection/AddConsoleCommandPass.php on line 61
```

In the browser, there are 2 messages :

```
(2/2) ContextErrorException
Warning: file_put_contents(/srv/http/ocim.formations/var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainerDeprecations.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied
in Kernel.php (line 648)

(1/2) FatalThrowableError
Call to undefined method Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineCacheBundle\Command\ContainsCommand::getDefaultName()
in AddConsoleCommandPass.php (line 61)
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineCacheBundle/issues/126#issuecomment-348507878), it may be caused by outdated Composer version, which uses older Symfony's Console Component. So when Composer has previously loaded older version of this class, it's not autoloaded again when your Symfony instance is trying to access this class later in `cache:clear` command.

The solution may be to update your Composer with `composer self-update`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I try composer self-update. I've got Composer version 1.6.4 now but it doen't change anything when I try composer update. Only in the browser, I've got now : (1/1) FatalErrorException

Compile Error: Cannot declare class Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Security\FirewallMap, because the name is already in use

Comment: You've already updated everything earlier so it won't update anything again. It just failed on post-update command. You should clear cache (try manually removing cache files for sure).

Comment: No, still the same error. It change again in the browser. With Attempted to call an undefined method named "getDefaultName" of class "Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineCacheBundle\Command\ContainsCommand".

Comment: @JakubMatczak: little typing error: `composer self-update` with an `r` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem today: We use `symfony/console` 3.4+ in our project, which tries to load the command-name via `getDefaultName`. But composer uses internally an [older version of `symfony/console`](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/1.10.6/composer.lock#L475) where this method does not exist, since it was [added in `v3.4.0`](https://github.com/symfony/console/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#340).

In this case a `composer self-update` won't help, but you can make sure to add the `command` to your service-definition like so:

```
services:
  myvendorname.mypackagename.foo.command:
    class: MyVendorName\MyPackageName\Command\FooCommand
    tags:
    - { name: 'console.command', command: 'foo' }
#                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#                         This is the important part
```

This will load the name [directly from the service definition](https://github.com/symfony/console/blob/v3.4.15/DependencyInjection/AddConsoleCommandPass.php#L47-L53) and does not try to [call `getDefaultName()`](https://github.com/symfony/console/blob/v3.4.15/DependencyInjection/AddConsoleCommandPass.php#L61).